# Oracle PL/SQL repeating users, adding number of repetition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this table with empty column:

```
+----+------+--------+--------+
| id | user | first  | last   |
+----+------+--------+--------+
|  1 |      | Ivan   | Horvat | 
|  2 |      | Matija | Horvat | 
|  3 |      | Ivan   | Horvat | 
|  4 |      |Tomislav| Jurisic| 
|  5 |      | Ivan   | Horvat | 
+----+------+--------+--------+
```

I need to do a couple of things for this function, but the added numbers for the repetition users is not working. Example: multiple Ivan Horvat - `ihorvat, ihorvat1, ihorvat1`. And it must be `ihorvat, ihorvat1,  ihorvat2`...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Function TMP_korisnicko_ime
RETURN  INTEGER
IS
   v_korisnicko_ime varchar2(60);
   broj INTEGER;
   cursor c1 is
     select ID, IME, PREZIME from T_OSOBE where KORISNICKO_IME IS NULL;
BEGIN
   FOR OSOBA_REC in c1
   LOOP
      v_korisnicko_ime := TRANSLATE(LOWER(SUBSTR(OSOBA_REC.ime, 1, 1) || OSOBA_REC.prezime), 'ćčđšž', 'ccdsz');
      SELECT COUNT(*) INTO broj from RIS.T_OSOBE WHERE nvl(korisnicko_ime,'') = v_korisnicko_ime;
      IF broj > 0 THEN
        v_korisnicko_ime := v_korisnicko_ime ||  TO_CHAR(broj);
      END IF;
      UPDATE T_OSOBE set KORISNICKO_IME = v_korisnicko_ime WHERE ID = OSOBA_REC.ID;   
      END LOOP;
   RETURN broj;
   COMMIT;
END;
```

End result:

```
+----+--------+--------+--------+
| id | user   | first  | last   |
+----+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 |ihorvat | Ivan   | Horvat | 
|  2 |mhorvat | Matija | Horvat | 
|  3 |ihorvat1| Ivan   | Horvat | 
|  4 |tjurisic|Tomislav| Jurisic| 
|  5 |ihorvat1| Ivan   | Horvat | 
+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Show us the final result as well.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need PL/SQL. Besides, you could have adjusted my answer in the previous question you asked (and never replied to) about *selecting* username (while this one is about *updating* the table; yes, sometimes people have problems in switching from one to another, so - here you go).

Table contents:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID CUSER           FIRST    LAST
---------- --------------- -------- -------
         1                 Ivan     Horvat
         2                 Matija   Horvat
         3                 Ivan     Babić
         4                 Tomislav Jurišić
         5                 Ivan     Horvat
```

Update username:

```
SQL> merge into test t
  2       using (with tuser
  3                   as (select id,
  4                              translate (lower (substr (first, 1, 1) || last),
  5                                         'ĐŠŽĆČđšžćč',
  6                                         'DSZCCdszcc')
  7                                 val
  8                         from test)
  9              select id,
 10                        val
 11                     || case
 12                           when row_number ()
 13                                   over (partition by val order by id) = 1
 14                           then
 15                              null
 16                           else
 17                                row_number ()
 18                                   over (partition by val order by id)
 19                              - 1
 20                        end
 21                        as cuser
 22                from tuser) x
 23          on (x.id = t.id)
 24  when matched
 25  then
 26     update set t.cuser = x.cuser;

5 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test order by id;

        ID CUSER           FIRST    LAST
---------- --------------- -------- -------
         1 ihorvat         Ivan     Horvat
         2 mhorvat         Matija   Horvat
         3 ibabic          Ivan     Babić
         4 tjurisic        Tomislav Jurišić
         5 ihorvat1        Ivan     Horvat

SQL>
```

Comment: This comment didn't help me then and isn't helping me now. I know I should've send some feedback and sorry for that.

Comment: Why exactly doesn't this help? Doesn't it do what you asked?

Comment: If user is named Ivan Horvat his username must be "ihorvat". Then his first repetition must be "ihorvat1", after that "ihorvat2" etc. Your code on first repetition sets user as "ihorvat2". Also, I would like this problem solved on my code. I hope I'm not too confusing.

Comment: Aha, ihorvat**1** is the first one after ihorvat. It's a minor change (`-1` in line #19) so I fixed it. As of your code: why would you want to do it *your way*? It is highly inefficient as it does it row-by-row (in a loop), which is slow-by-slow. Don't do that.

Comment: I am new to this and just trying to go step by step. I wrote that code and wanted to first fix things on that code, and then go on. Thanks for advice

Comment: Since you new to this a word of advice. Don't go step-by-step if that step involves doing a loop. For SQL that is entirely the wrong way of think about the problem. Think instead in terms of SETs of things not in individual ITEMs (rows). The further/longer you think item by item the longer and harder writing better SQL becomes.**So _step-0_  No Loops**.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `row_number()` analytic function grouped by first and last names together within a SQL query :

```
SQL> create table t_osobe_ as
with t as 
(
select t.*,
       concat(substr(lower(ime),1,1),lower(prezime)) as "user",
       row_number() over (partition by ime,prezime order by id)-1 as nr
  from t_osobe t
)  
select t.id, case when nr > 0 then concat("user",nr) else "user" end as "user",
       t.ime, t.prezime
  from t
 order by id;

SQL> drop table t_osobe;

SQL> rename t_osobe_ to t_osobe;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e1925af70f3fe6c3eb8b7d3853e92ca)</kbd>

provided you don't have any constraints or indexes, those needed to be defined,  on the table.

**Update :** If you'd like to go on with your current PL/SQL code, then consider using :

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure TMP_korisnicko_ime IS
  v_korisnicko_ime varchar2(60);
  broj             INTEGER;
  cursor c1 is
    select ID,
           lower(IME) as IME,
           lower(PREZIME) as PREZIME,
           row_number() over (partition by IME, PREZIME order by id) - 1 as broj
      from T_OSOBE
     where KORISNICKO_IME IS NULL;
BEGIN
  FOR OSOBA_REC in c1 
  LOOP

    v_korisnicko_ime := SUBSTR(OSOBA_REC.ime, 1, 1)||
                        TRANSLATE( OSOBA_REC.prezime,
                                  'ccdšz',
                                  'ccdsz'); 

    IF OSOBA_REC.broj > 0 THEN
      v_korisnicko_ime := v_korisnicko_ime || TO_CHAR(OSOBA_REC.broj);
    END IF;

    UPDATE T_OSOBE
       set KORISNICKO_IME = v_korisnicko_ime
     WHERE ID = OSOBA_REC.ID;
  END LOOP;

END;
/ 

SQL> exec TMP_korisnicko_ime;

SQL> commit;
```

*P.S: Considering you want to apply DML instead of a select statement, reverted function to a procedure.*

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=88c6fe636ccbb4784e5f58a9b69c9e33)</kbd>

Comment: This helped, but can I kindly ask you to just solve my problem on code I wrote in question? How to implement this row_number() in my code? Where to write it?

Comment: Now in the "prezime" is not getting it's first letter lower cased. I can't recognize the problem.

Comment: OK, fixed the problem @zagvir

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also, I didn't change it to procedure, I stayed with function. I added in function that "row_number()"... and everything works except this one letter in upper case

Comment: interesting. Well, I added a demo, too @zagvir .

Comment: @zagvir you can try to replace `lower(IME) ` with  `nls_lower(IME,'nls_sort=xcroatian')` also.

Comment: In demo there are selected values in table t_osobe t in column KORISNICKO_IME: iHorvat, mHorvat, iHorvat1, tJurisic, iHorvat2 and I would like them to be: ihorvat, mhorvat, ihorvat1, tjurisic, ihorvat2. Thanks in advance

Comment: excuse me, I didn't notice that you need lwer letters for surnames also @zagvir.  OK, changed now.

Comment: Here I am, a month later. I was looking your code and I can't really understand it. I understand the "with" syntax, but I don't know what's up with this "val". Could you please write some comments and explain it to a beginner. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi again @zagvir :) This time I couldn't understand what you mean by `"val"` ...

Comment: I just realised I commented on a wrong question, I don't even know how I managed to do that :D

Comment: Doesn't matter :) @zagvir

Answer (score 0):

This would best be solved with `ROW_NUMBER`. Here is a small procedure doing the update:

```
create or replace procedure update_username as
begin
  for rec in (
    select
      id, 
      lower(substr(firstname, 1, 1)) || lower(lastname) as lowername,
      row_number() over (partition by lower(substr(firstname, 1, 1)) || lower(lastname)
                         order by id) as rn
    from mytable t
  ) loop
    update mytable
    set username = rec.lowername || case when rec.rn > 1 then rec.rn - 1 end
    where id = rec.id;
  end loop;
end update_username;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c10562edd032c6fb10d046b89dc86453

With `rec in (select ...) loop` I am using an implicit cursor here, which I find much more convenient than an explicit cursor. You may want to add a `commit` somewhere inside the procedure (after each row or after all rows) or leave it as is and issue the commit outside the procedure (which I often prefer).

I've renamed the columns to firstname, lastname and username in order to avoid conflicts with SQL keywords.